# Why does netfilter not let userspace applications accept packets queued with ingress hook?

Tags: linux, kernel, firewall, packet, netfilter

I made a small module that just queues packets to userspace with NFPROTO_NETDEV protocol and NF_NETDEV_INGRESS hook. The module looks like this:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/panic.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <net/net_namespace.h>
#include <linux/skbuff.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/netdevice.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static unsigned int nf_myhookfn(void *priv,
                   struct sk_buff *skb,
                   const struct nf_hook_state *state)
{
   printk(KERN_ALERT "skb len is %u\n", skb->len);
   return NF_QUEUE_NR(1);
}

struct nf_hook_ops myhook = {
    .hook = nf_myhookfn,
    .pf = NFPROTO_NETDEV,
    .hooknum = NF_NETDEV_INGRESS,
    .priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST,
};

const char *devname = "enp0s3";

static int __init mymod_init(void){
   struct net_device *dev;
   read_lock(&dev_base_lock);
   for_each_netdev(&init_net, dev){
      if (!strcmp(dev->name, devname)){
         myhook.dev = dev;
         break;
      }
   }
   read_unlock(&dev_base_lock);

   nf_register_net_hook(&init_net, &myhook);
   printk(KERN_INFO "module loaded\n");

   return 0;
}
 
static void __exit mymod_exit(void){
   nf_unregister_net_hook(&init_net, &myhook);
   printk(KERN_INFO "module unloaded\n");
}
 
module_init(mymod_init);
module_exit(mymod_exit);
```

I'm pretty sure you can also queue them with nftables instead, I just couldn't get queue statement to work with netdev family chain on my system.

Then I used the [netfilter_queue example application](https://git.netfilter.org/libnetfilter_queue/tree/examples/nf-queue.c) to verify that it works but I've noticed that the packets aren't actually handled by the kernel network stack despite the application setting the NF_ACCEPT verdict for them. Instead, I'm getting 2 warnings in dmesg:

```
[ 5737.195168] module loaded
[ 5748.189915] skb len is 76
[ 5748.190606] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 5748.190608] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 13259 at net/netfilter/nf_queue.c:291 nf_reinject+0x3f/0x1d0
[ 5748.190617] Modules linked in: mod(OE) nfnetlink_queue nfnetlink_log nft_log nft_queue nf_tables nfnetlink tls uinput snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer qrtr rfkill vboxsf sunrpc snd_intel8x0 snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm snd_timer intel_rapl_msr snd intel_rapl_common rapl soundcore joydev eeprom pktcdvd vboxguest i2c_piix4 zram vmwgfx crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel polyval_clmulni polyval_generic e1000 drm_ttm_helper ghash_clmulni_intel ttm sha512_ssse3 serio_raw video wmi ata_generic pata_acpi fuse
[ 5748.190649] Unloaded tainted modules: mod(OE):1 [last unloaded: mod(OE)]
[ 5748.190653] CPU: 2 PID: 13259 Comm: nf-queue Tainted: G           OE      6.1.12-200.fc37.x86_64 #1
[ 5748.190656] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[ 5748.190657] RIP: 0010:nf_reinject+0x3f/0x1d0
[ 5748.190661] Code: 83 ec 08 0f b6 57 31 4c 8b 67 10 48 8b 4f 50 0f b6 47 30 80 fa 07 74 41 80 fa 0a 0f 84 e9 00 00 00 80 fa 02 0f 84 d0 00 00 00 <0f> 0b 0f 0b be 01 00 00 00 4c 89 e7 e8 d0 37 f4 ff 48 89 ef e8 e8
[ 5748.190663] RSP: 0018:ffff9ea38d883968 EFLAGS: 00010206
[ 5748.190665] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: ffffffff84df2e00
[ 5748.190666] RDX: 0000000000000005 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff8ee5e1a38800
[ 5748.190667] RBP: ffff8ee5e1a38800 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000008
[ 5748.190668] R10: ffffffffc06f5770 R11: ffffffffffffffff R12: ffff8ee443f20400
[ 5748.190670] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000001
[ 5748.190671] FS:  00007f96b33c1b80(0000) GS:ffff8ee657d00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 5748.190691] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 5748.190694] CR2: 00007f96b344f270 CR3: 000000000116a000 CR4: 00000000000406e0
[ 5748.190699] Call Trace:
[ 5748.190702]  <TASK>
[ 5748.190708]  nfqnl_recv_verdict+0x2fc/0x540 [nfnetlink_queue]
[ 5748.190716]  ? _raw_spin_lock+0x13/0x40
[ 5748.190722]  nfnetlink_rcv_msg+0x184/0x2c0 [nfnetlink]
[ 5748.190729]  ? __switch_to+0x2ef/0x420
[ 5748.190737]  ? nfnetlink_unbind+0xa0/0xa0 [nfnetlink]
[ 5748.190742]  netlink_rcv_skb+0x51/0x100
[ 5748.190746]  netlink_unicast+0x21e/0x360
[ 5748.190749]  netlink_sendmsg+0x242/0x4a0
[ 5748.190751]  sock_sendmsg+0x5f/0x70
[ 5748.190756]  __sys_sendto+0x11c/0x170
[ 5748.190761]  __x64_sys_sendto+0x20/0x30
[ 5748.190763]  do_syscall_64+0x5b/0x80
[ 5748.190769]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x17/0x40
[ 5748.190772]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x80
[ 5748.190775]  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x1ef/0x690
[ 5748.190780]  ? exc_page_fault+0x70/0x170
[ 5748.190785]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x63/0xcd
[ 5748.190788] RIP: 0033:0x7f96b34d9de7
[ 5748.190809] Code: 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb b8 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 80 3d 1d d8 0c 00 00 41 89 ca 74 10 b8 2c 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 71 c3 55 48 83 ec 30 44 89 4c 24 2c 4c 89 44
[ 5748.190811] RSP: 002b:00007fff30778f58 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002c
[ 5748.190814] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007fff30779f60 RCX: 00007f96b34d9de7
[ 5748.190816] RDX: 000000000000002c RSI: 00007fff30778f60 RDI: 0000000000000003
[ 5748.190817] RBP: 00007fff30779fc0 R08: 00007f96b35b7200 R09: 000000000000000c
[ 5748.190818] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 0000000000001000
[ 5748.190820] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000001000 R15: 0000000000000000
[ 5748.190823]  </TASK>
[ 5748.190824] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[ 5748.190846] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 5748.190848] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 13259 at net/netfilter/nf_queue.c:315 nf_reinject+0x41/0x1d0
[ 5748.190852] Modules linked in: mod(OE) nfnetlink_queue nfnetlink_log nft_log nft_queue nf_tables nfnetlink tls uinput snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer qrtr rfkill vboxsf sunrpc snd_intel8x0 snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm snd_timer intel_rapl_msr snd intel_rapl_common rapl soundcore joydev eeprom pktcdvd vboxguest i2c_piix4 zram vmwgfx crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel polyval_clmulni polyval_generic e1000 drm_ttm_helper ghash_clmulni_intel ttm sha512_ssse3 serio_raw video wmi ata_generic pata_acpi fuse
[ 5748.190892] Unloaded tainted modules: mod(OE):1 [last unloaded: mod(OE)]
[ 5748.190895] CPU: 2 PID: 13259 Comm: nf-queue Tainted: G        W  OE      6.1.12-200.fc37.x86_64 #1
[ 5748.190898] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[ 5748.190899] RIP: 0010:nf_reinject+0x41/0x1d0
[ 5748.190902] Code: 08 0f b6 57 31 4c 8b 67 10 48 8b 4f 50 0f b6 47 30 80 fa 07 74 41 80 fa 0a 0f 84 e9 00 00 00 80 fa 02 0f 84 d0 00 00 00 0f 0b <0f> 0b be 01 00 00 00 4c 89 e7 e8 d0 37 f4 ff 48 89 ef e8 e8 fa ff
[ 5748.190904] RSP: 0018:ffff9ea38d883968 EFLAGS: 00010206
[ 5748.190907] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: ffffffff84df2e00
[ 5748.190908] RDX: 0000000000000005 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff8ee5e1a38800
[ 5748.190909] RBP: ffff8ee5e1a38800 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000008
[ 5748.190910] R10: ffffffffc06f5770 R11: ffffffffffffffff R12: ffff8ee443f20400
[ 5748.190912] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000001
[ 5748.190914] FS:  00007f96b33c1b80(0000) GS:ffff8ee657d00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 5748.190916] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 5748.190917] CR2: 00007f96b344f270 CR3: 000000000116a000 CR4: 00000000000406e0
[ 5748.190919] Call Trace:
[ 5748.190920]  <TASK>
[ 5748.190923]  nfqnl_recv_verdict+0x2fc/0x540 [nfnetlink_queue]
[ 5748.190930]  ? _raw_spin_lock+0x13/0x40
[ 5748.190935]  nfnetlink_rcv_msg+0x184/0x2c0 [nfnetlink]
[ 5748.190942]  ? __switch_to+0x2ef/0x420
[ 5748.190950]  ? nfnetlink_unbind+0xa0/0xa0 [nfnetlink]
[ 5748.190954]  netlink_rcv_skb+0x51/0x100
[ 5748.190957]  netlink_unicast+0x21e/0x360
[ 5748.190960]  netlink_sendmsg+0x242/0x4a0
[ 5748.190963]  sock_sendmsg+0x5f/0x70
[ 5748.190965]  __sys_sendto+0x11c/0x170
[ 5748.190970]  __x64_sys_sendto+0x20/0x30
[ 5748.190973]  do_syscall_64+0x5b/0x80
[ 5748.190977]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x17/0x40
[ 5748.190980]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x80
[ 5748.190983]  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x1ef/0x690
[ 5748.190988]  ? exc_page_fault+0x70/0x170
[ 5748.190993]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x63/0xcd
[ 5748.190996] RIP: 0033:0x7f96b34d9de7
[ 5748.191001] Code: 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb b8 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 80 3d 1d d8 0c 00 00 41 89 ca 74 10 b8 2c 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 71 c3 55 48 83 ec 30 44 89 4c 24 2c 4c 89 44
[ 5748.191003] RSP: 002b:00007fff30778f58 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002c
[ 5748.191005] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007fff30779f60 RCX: 00007f96b34d9de7
[ 5748.191007] RDX: 000000000000002c RSI: 00007fff30778f60 RDI: 0000000000000003
[ 5748.191008] RBP: 00007fff30779fc0 R08: 00007f96b35b7200 R09: 000000000000000c
[ 5748.191009] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 0000000000001000
[ 5748.191010] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000001000 R15: 0000000000000000
[ 5748.191013]  </TASK>
[ 5748.191014] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[ 5753.258933] skb len is 46
[ 5754.285780] skb len is 46
[ 5755.312265] skb len is 46
[ 5771.116041] module unloaded
```

I looked at the [code in question](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2/source/net/netfilter/nf_queue.c#L291) and it does indeed look like nf_reinject isn't supposed to reaccept packets with protocol families other than NFPROTO_BRIDGE, NFPROTO_IPV4 and NFPROTO_IPV6 (a.k.a. NFPROTO_INET). I've noticed that nf_reinject accepts pointer to network namespace, meanwhile ingress hooks pointer resides in [net_device structure](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L2210), so I tried feeding this pointer to nf_reinject directly, but it didn't work. I would no longer get warnings but the issue remained.

This all leads me to believe that there is a reason for this behaviour. I don't know for sure though, any clues are appreciated.